# Malloc is not allocating enough memory, despite being hardcoded to allocate exactly two characters

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, pass-by-reference, c-strings

I have a function that, given a pointer to a char array *string* (Passed by reference), a char *character* (passed by value), and an unsigned short int *length* (passed by reference), is supposed to, if *string* has already been allocated, re-allocate *string* one char longer in size ((length + 2) * sizeof(char)), and then increment *length* by one, setting the last two characters equal to *character* and the null terminator, respectively. If *string* has not yet been allocated, it instead allocates *string* with two characters in length (2 * sizeof(char)), before initializing the characters. However, when it sets the last character (index of *length*), it segfaults.

```
void appendCharacterToString(char** string, char character, unsigned short int * length) {

    if (*string != NULL) {
        *string = (char* ) realloc(*string, (*length + 2) * sizeof(char));
        ++*length;
    }
    else {
        *string = (char* ) malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
        *length = 1;
    }

    *string[*length - 1] = character;
    *string[*length] = 0;
}
```

When running it in gdb, I was able to determine that the initially allocated array, despite being hardcoded to allocate two chars worth of memory, only allocate one char, which, strangely enough, is already initialized to null.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
appendCharacterToString (string=0x7fffffffe0d8,
    character=110 'n', length=0x7fffffffe0d0)
    at hangmanstringutils.c:24
24          *string[*length] = 0;
(gdb)
(gdb) print string
$1 = (char **) 0x7fffffffe0d8
(gdb) print *string
$2 = 0x5555555592a0 "n"
(gdb) print *length
$3 = 1
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) break hangmanstringutils.c:12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x555555555612: file hangmanstringutils.c, line 14.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/joseph/code/hangman/hangman
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, appendCharacterToString (
    string=0x7fffffffe0d8, character=110 'n',
    length=0x7fffffffe0d0) at hangmanstringutils.c:14
14          if (*string != NULL) {
(gdb) print *string
$4 = 0x0
(gdb) print *length
$5 = 0
(gdb) break 19
Breakpoint 2 at 0x55555555565a: file hangmanstringutils.c, line 19.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, appendCharacterToString (
    string=0x7fffffffe0d8, character=110 'n',
    length=0x7fffffffe0d0) at hangmanstringutils.c:19
19              *string = (char* ) malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
(gdb) print *string
$6 = 0x0
(gdb) print *length
$7 = 0
(gdb) break 21
Breakpoint 3 at 0x555555555677: file hangmanstringutils.c, line 23.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, appendCharacterToString (
    string=0x7fffffffe0d8, character=110 'n',
    length=0x7fffffffe0d0) at hangmanstringutils.c:23
23          *string[*length - 1] = character;
(gdb) print *string
$8 = 0x5555555592a0 ""
(gdb) print *length
$9 = 1
(gdb) print *string[0]
$10 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) print *string[1]
Cannot access memory at address 0x2c0
(gdb)
```

Comment: `print *string[1]` does not access the character at index 1 of `string`. It accesses the character pointed to by `string[1]`, which is the bytes in memory after `*string`. You want `print (*string)[1]`. Similarly, in the source code, you want `(*string)[length] = 0;`.

Comment: In the future, provide a [mre] when asking debugging questions.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1, by definition, so multiplying by it is a no-op.  You can safely omit that.

Comment: Instead of GDB, you might be better off using Valgrind to show you where you first access out-of-bounds memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print *string[1]` does not access the character at index 1 of `*string`. It is `*(string[1])`, not `(*string)[1]`. It accesses the character pointed to by `string[1]`, and `string[1]` denotes the bytes in memory after `*string`. You want `print (*string)[1]` in the debugger command. Similarly, in the source code, you want:

```
(*string)[*length - 1] = character;
(*string)[*length] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** (prepended to this answer)
The OP's problem stems from not recognising the operator `[]` has a higher precedence than `*`.

Thus, `string[x]` is dealt with **before** dereferencing is done.
The code attempts to dereference a garbage address and triggers the error.

The simple fix is to put `*string` inside a pair of these: `()`. Eg: `(*string)[x]`
(The indirection used in this function serves only to boggle the reader.)

The proper fix is for the OP to re-write the function eliminating the unnecessary complications of indirection...

Continuing with my previous response...

---

Too much code! I don't really want to try to understand what is going wrong with that code.

1. `void` function necessitates using indirection for two parameters.
2. Avoiding `strlen()` in favour of complexity is a bad choice.
3. *Casting* the `void *` return from `malloc()` & `realloc()` is bad practice
4. Not reading the manual: `realloc()` acts like `malloc()` if its first parameter is `NULL`.
5. `sizeof(char)` might make sense if program might be used with larger character types.
6. "Trusting" that the caller hasn't altered the value of `length` inappropriately.
7. Not verifying that heap allocation succeeded.

Then, there's this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *appendCharacterToString( char *str, char ch ) {
    size_t len = str == NULL ? 0 : strlen( str );
    char *tmp = realloc( str, len + 2 );
    if( !tmp ) {
        perror( "allocation failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    str = tmp;

    str[ len++ ] = ch;
    str[ len   ] = 0;

    return str;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *str = NULL;

    str = appendCharacterToString( str, 'f' );
    str = appendCharacterToString( str, 'o' );
    str = appendCharacterToString( str, 'o' );
    puts( str );
    str = appendCharacterToString( str, 'b' );
    str = appendCharacterToString( str, 'a' );
    str = appendCharacterToString( str, 'r' );
    puts( str );

    free( str );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
foo
foobar
```

Please don't ask why bad/overly-complicated code doesn't work.

Develop a sense for what is correct, clear, concise code... and what is not...

Comment: You do not need tmp here as str is a local variable

Comment: type of len is incorrect

Comment: function should not kill the program.

Comment: @0___________ Good point. Although... Since there may be times when "failure is not an option", using a 2nd pointer variable isn't a bad habit to get into...

Comment: `*sizeof(char) might make sense if program might be used with larger character types.*` - false - `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1. CHAR_BIT can be != 8 but sizeof(char) is **always** 1

Comment: @0___________ "_type of len is incorrect_" Valid point! Corrected. Thank you...

Comment: @0___________ "_function should not kill the program_" OP can decide how to handle allocation failure in their circumstances... Since the function seems to be in support of the game _Hangman_, using heap instead of a stack buffer is another bad choice... But, who can say? Not you, and not me...

Comment: @0___________ You need to sit down and talk this out with Eric... My comment was in reference to "wide characters", not `CHAR_BIT`... Are you having a _grumpy_ day???

Comment: No, how `sizeof(char)`  (as it is always 1)will help with wider types of characters (not char)? in this case it has to be done different way  example: `wchar *string = malloc(length * sizeof(*string))`;

Comment: @0___________ Your last example would be the right way to write the code... at the time when the OP starts to grapple with wide characters... Writing 'Hangman' as a programming exercise indicates the OP is a beginner... No point in overwhelming someone trying to learn. (Doing so could put some people off completely. Ever have a teacher who did that?)

Comment: main invokes undefined behavior

Comment: @0___________ `main()` is only a demonstration of how the function could be used... Not intended to be robust or complete...

Comment: @Fe2O3 "Avoiding strlen() in favour of complexity is a bad choice." --> Perhaps.  If calling code already knows the string length (and needs it updated), passing in the address of the length is reasonable..  Using type `unsigned short` is strange, yet without seeing the calling code, what is best is too subjective.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica While I hold your opinion in high esteem, since this is (apparently) 'Hangman' (expensively appending one character at a time to a growing heap buffer), it seems to me that this function or the caller would be better served by calling `strlen()` on the actual pointer (if not NULL). Hardly more expensive than hoping the value of `*length` doesn't get out of step with the reality of the string's actual length... Just me... the minimalist... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Fair enough my friend.  Concerning "expensively appending one character at a time to a growing heap buffer" --> I suspect _good_ allocators handle this about as good as user code would given it is a common use pattern.  As the years have gone on, I see library code getting better and the effort for me to out-perform it is more expensive in code and maintenance.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "_Nothing in this “answer” answers why OP..._" That depends entirely on what one perceives to be the OP's problem: "SEG_FAULT because the code is incorrect" OR, simply, "the approach is flawed," The first 3 words of this "answer" point out the OP's problem. "_Too much code!_"... This answer is a compromise as a balm to the OP's ego (mucking with heap allocation.) In reality, fulfilling the purpose of this function should be an even simpler approach. Of course, you're welcome to have your perception of the OP's problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect PS: thanks for reminding me to send $20 to Wikipedia... A very useful resource... `:-)`

Comment: Side-note: `(*string)[x]` could also be expressed as `string[0][x]` to avoid the somewhat ugly parens. Or for extra ugliness, but more code-golfiness, you could use the highly non-intuitive `x[*string]`. :-) (Seriously though, never use that last one for any purpose but code golf and writing obfuscated code for kicks; if you use it in production code, I preemptively approve any punitive measures taken by your colleagues who have to deal with your horrible code)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'll never wrap my head around the way SO answers swing between accepting code like this OP's (void function requiring a parameter that is a double pointer), then flaming other OP's who've written code using triple indirection pointers... Oh, well... :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have many issues in this code. I would strongly discourage using side effects.

```
char  *appendCharacterToString(char* string, char character, size_t *length) 
{
    size_t newLength = string ? *length + 2 : 2;
    string = realloc(string, newLength);

    if(string)
    {
        string[newLength - 2] = character;
        string[newLength - 1] = 0;
        *length = newLength - 1;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: How does one handle the memory leak when the _nth_ allocation fails? Suddenly `string` is NULL and `*length = ???`... Which variable you gonna trust?

Comment: @Fe2O3  (*`Which variable you gonna trust?`*  definitely not your understanding of C)`length` does not change in that case. Caller's  string references the previous allocated memory. Function string is local and it does not affect the caller's one. Realloc does not destroy the previously allocated block if new allocation fails.  :)

Comment: Ah ha! That makes sense... kinda... Now it's up to the **caller** to use a temporary pointer to catch the return from this function (in case of failure...)... Many ways to skin a cat...

Comment: @Fe2O3 caller has to know if the allocation failed and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Minor: `newLength` better as `newSize` as a string's size is one more than its length and the object represents the new size.

Comment: Nothing in this “answer” answers why OP is getting a segment fault. They need to know `*string[index]` is wrong in their code.